# Eclipse - Where to place image files

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been developing a clone of Space Invaders for a while, and the image assets I use worked fine when I defined the exact path (I.E. `E:\Images\picture.png`). However, since my project is on a data stick and different USBs on different PCs use different letters, I thought it would be a good idea to place the assets with my source code so they would always work. So, here is my new image load code:

```
        if(type.equals("player"))
        {
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("/assets/Bullet.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(type.equals("alien"))
        {
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("/assets/BulletAlien.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I created a folder called `assets` inside my source code directory (i.e. `E:\<eclipse workspace>\<project name>\src\assets`) and filled it with all of my image files. However, every time I try and run the program I get `javax.imageio.IIOException` on all the images I try and load; the reason given is "Cannot find input file". How can I fix this?

Comment: Side note: Use `equals` to compare Strings, not `==`. Rumors saying that programmers who use `==` are suffering in hell.

Comment: Have you tried `assets/Bullet.png` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative root for files is not your source file, but your project file (the one with the `.metadata` in it). Therefore, you either need to move your image folder to the parent directory or call `new File("src/assets/XXX.png")`